# asp.net mvc 4 Filter table using Datepicker

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm trying to filter a table when a date in the datepicker was click. What I did was send the date clicked as JSON to my controller using $.get and then use linq to filter the table then return the view with the filtered table as my model. I used firebug to check the response and it shows me the correct html with the tables matching the date clicked but it isn't showing in the browser. How do I fix this?

```
$("#adminCalendar").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        $.get("/Administrator/DateFilter", { "date": date }, null);
    }
});
```

The controller:

```
    public ActionResult DateFilter(string date)
    {
        var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToShortDateString();

        var transactions = (from transaction in db.Transactions
                           select transaction).ToList();


        var tran = from transaction in transactions
                   where transaction.OccassionDate.ToShortDateString() == dateTime
                   select transaction;


        return View("Index", tran);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request something via AJAX you should do something with response. In your case you can do something like this:

```
$.get("/Administrator/DateFilter", { "date": date }).done(function (result) {
    $('#myDiv').html(result);
});
```

or

```
$('#myDiv').load("/Administrator/DateFilter", { date: date });
```

You should also add element with id `myDiv` that display result of your request.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And change your result in controller from View to PartialView to avoid sending result with layout.

You can also change ajax request to `window.location = '/Administrator/DateFilter?date=' + date`. In that case you keep View result of your action method and you don't need add `myDiv` element.

Comment: but for the first solution it should be a partial view! else whole page will be again displayed in that div.

Comment: Thanks. But I had to use .html('') before load() to make work. And also I don't have that done method in my intellisense?

Comment: I don't know what version of jQuery you using but `done` has been added in version 1.5: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/